# Is there a list of permitted fields for phonegap contacts.find?

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, abaddressbook

I'm looking at phonegap to replace my app.

Is there a list anywhere (I've looked and cant seem to find it) of the valid values of fields to be searched

```
   var fields = ["*"] ;  //what specific fields can I use.
   navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```

if I use `*` for fields it finds stuff alright but I should be able to specify fields.  if I'm searching for something in the url and I put

```
   var fields = ["url"] ;  //what specific fields can I use.
   navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```

it doesn't find any contacts.  Is there a list of valid fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

I found eventually that the you really need to get the existing fields from whatever platform you are on first and then use these to work with.

I wrote up an [article here with details for iphone.](http://write.intellectualmollusc.net/2012/03/example-of-creating-a-full-contact-with-phonegap/)